# Jeditable + Datepicker query plugins to get the data on div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field.
I would like to use Jeditable in order to tie datepicker to div element.
Some hints how to make it?

```
   //html code
   <input type="text" id="datepicker">
   <div id="datepickerDiv"> get date </div>
```

--

```
    // javascript script code
    $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); // it works
            $( "#datepickerDiv" ).datepicker(); // it does not work
    });
```

References:
[Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)
[Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: maybe you can find your in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642136/jeditable-with-jquery-ui-datepicker