# Best way to allow editing of a datetime value in a jeditable environment?

Tags: jquery, mysql, datetime, jeditable

I use Jeditable to allow editing of a table on my page. It updates a MySQL table and it all works fine.

I would like to add the ability to edit a datetime value as well. So I tried using jquery.jeditable.datepicker.js to do the job. But it works only with date values not datetime values.

```
$('.editTimeIn').editable('save.php', { 
    type        : 'datepicker',
        datepicker: {
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            numberOfMonths: 2
        }
});
```

I need to be able to give the user the ability to pick the date and time. What recommendations do you have for this functionality?
If possible please use examples.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642136/jeditable-with-jquery-ui-datepicker#1406886) + the second comment below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jeditable](https://appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/) documentation.

> (String) **type**: Input type to use. Default input types are ***text***,
>   ***textarea*** or ***select***. Additional input types are provided using custom
>   input type API.

So if you take a closer look in [`jeditable additional input types`](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable/blob/master/js/jquery.jeditable.inputs.js) you will see that you could use

> `timepicker` type (dependency of [`timepicker`](http://jquery.com/plugins/project/timepicker))

or

> a `time` input type (perhaps this is the best way in case you need
>   something quick and without any other plugin dependancy).

A simple example of `time` input type can be found in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcqu5qm7/1/)

**EDIT**

You could also try to extend additional input types by adding `datetime-local` input type such as below (just a simple demo)

```
$.editable.addInputType('datetime', {
/* Create input element. */
element : function(settings, original) {
    // pattern is fallback for browsers not supporting datetime-local   
    var datetime_local = $('<input id="datetime_" type="datetime-local" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" required />');
    $(this).append(datetime_local);         
var hidden = $('<input type="hidden">');
$(this).append(hidden);
return(hidden);
},
submit : function(settings, original) {
    var value = $('input:#datetime_').val();
    $("input", this).val(value);
}
});
```

Please check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcqu5qm7/4/) also to view the changes

Comment: HI #Peter Darmis this is exactly what I'm looking for. However the fiddle withe the date isn't working. The end of the edit must have a value such as 2017-12-15 09:15:00  Can you show me how to do that in the fiddle?

Comment: @KeithDKaiser if you mean that when you submitted the form the date value was undefined then check the update.

Comment: Any way to use dropdown or other method to select the date and the time (similar to what you did in the first fiddle)?

Comment: @KeithDKaiser the UI of the `datetime-local` type depends strictly to the browser as seen here for the `time` type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time. The only way to use `select` for both date and time would be to write an additional type in `jeditable` similar to the `time` type that would also contain date.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from [source file](https://github.com/qertoip/jeditable-datepicker/blob/master/test/javascripts/jquery.jeditable.datepicker.js) of jeditable. Look at the end of the fie

```
  if (settings.datepicker) {
    jQuery.extend(datepicker, settings.datepicker);
  }

  input.datepicker(datepicker);
```

What it's actually doing is applying jquery ui datepicker to your input element.

[JQuery ui Datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) doesn't have the ability to change datetime.
Alternatively you can find another library which support this. or you can request a feature from [jeditable developers](https://github.com/qertoip/jeditable-datepicker) on github.

I recommend you to find any other library because I doubt that developers would help you because it's been six or seven years since they worked on it. and you shouldn't use depreciated libraries.